# Select elements with specific class name Sizzle

Tags: javascript, css, sizzle

How to select all elements with specific class name in a HTML document. I used to do this with

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
```

But I want to do the same in older versions of browsers, so I chose to use the Sizzle library. How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you tried the [Sizzle docs](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation)?

Comment: why not simply use jQuery??

Comment: I would recommend that you use JQuery instead. That way you can do `$('.classname')` check http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: @iJay jQuery itself is using Sizzle for selecting elements. I don't want to include more javascript in my page

Answer (score 7):

The [main function exposed by Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#sizzle-string-selector-domelementdomdocument-context-array-results-) is used for selecting elements:

```
var elems = Sizzle(".classname");
```

In modern browsers that will simply delegate to `document.querySelectorAll`.